# MySQL JOIN 3 tables search by WHERE on ID from 1

Tags: mysql

I seem to be struggling grasping the concept of joining 3 tables on one ID.

USER Table
`|id    |
 |:----:|
 |1     |
 |2     |`

POST table
`|id    |userid | content|
 |:----:|:----:|:----:|
 |1     |1     |HELLO |
 |2     |1     |THERE |
 |3     |2     |WORLD |`

friend table 
`|id    | userid | friendid |
 |:----:|:------:|:--------:|
 | 1    | 1      | 2        |`

I want to provide the ID from the USER table, and get ALL the CONTENT from POSTS where the POST.USERID is the FRIEND.USERID and FRIEND.FRIENDID
So USER.ID = '1' would bring back all the POST.CONTENT(in this case).

Really hope you can help, been annoying me for hours.

Comment: Can you show an example? What's the expected output?

Comment: Get all `content` from POST, when I give the USER.ID of '1'. USER.ID would join with FRIEND.USERID, and FRIEND.USERID and FRIEND.FRIENDID would match the POST.USERID.

Comment: Then what did you mean by `Friend` table? Is there anything you want from friend table ?

Comment: 2 USER's would be joined together by FRIEND. so if the connection is made on the FRIEND table, USER 1 would see USER 2's POST.CONTENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your description, you would not need to join to the user table, you could directly use the friends table, as you have the userid there. But this should give you all posts from userid 5 and his that persons friends.

```
SELECT post.* 
FROM post 
INNER JOIN friends ON post.userid = friends.userid OR post.userid = friends.friendid 
WHERE friends.userid =1
```

To not query duplicates use this:

```
SELECT post.*, users.firstname
FROM post 
INNER JOIN users ON users.userid = post.userid
WHERE post.userid = 1

UNION

SELECT post.*, users.firstname 
FROM friends
INNER JOIN post ON friends.friendid = post.userid 
INNER JOIN users ON users.userid = friends.friendid
WHERE friends.userid = 1
```

Comment: That's where I must have been overthinking the query.

Except, the first one you posted..
'SELECT post . * 
FROM post
INNER JOIN friends ON post.userid = friends.userid
OR post.userid = friends.friendid
WHERE friends.userid =1'

Seems to work perfect.
The edited on, on the other hand, doesn't produce the same results.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the first one was wrong, gonna check it again

Comment: Alright, added the first query again, and another one which removes the duplicates

Comment: Thank you, it works brilliantly, but I have a mistake on my part I forgot to insist. I do actually need a link to the USER table, so I could fetch user.firstname etc.

Comment: Easy, added the joins to the usertable.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect. 
Do you have any recommended sources for me to learn MySQL properly, everything I've found on the internet gets me confused?

Comment: Hm maybe try [sqlisland](http://wwwlgis.informatik.uni-kl.de/extra/game/) it is a game in which you use sql to solve some problems. Don't know how far it goes into more complex queries, but I think there are queries with joins. Also a lot of understanding comes with practice, so when you keep working with sql at some point it will make 'click', just don't give up